# INR currency format in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have amount in indian rupee just like 123456 but i want to display it like this 1,23,456.for that i am trying this one.

```
value = 123456;
Console.WriteLine("Format:  " + value.ToString("0,0",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
Console.WriteLine();
```

And output is. :`1,234,56` and so on.

But i want to display like  `1,23,456` instead of `1,234,56`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job for you, but if you need it dynamically then you have to use current culture or create one when needed.

```
 int value = 123456;
 CultureInfo InCulture = new CultureInfo("hi-IN");           
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = InCulture;
 Console.WriteLine("Format:  " + value.ToString("0,0", InCulture));
```

Since you have tagged asp.net do give a try to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/334820/Using-Globalization-and-Localization-in-ASP-NET).